# Odoo - List view and Checkbox

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In the Odoo administration, I want to have a list view with my own checkboxes.
For now, all I could manage was to create a list view with a boolean, which does look like a checkbox, but it can not be checked or unchecked simply by clicking on it: (See the "Available on Wordpress column)

[image: Checkboxes]

Is there any way I can create a standard checkboxes just like the ones on the left?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the edit mode in the view.

Example xml code for tree view:

```
<tree string="List" editable="top" create="false" edit="true">
```